Why does configure script expect an absolute directory name for --prefix?
I'm trying to use a non-absolute directory name for --prefix:
$ ./configure --prefix=xxx
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: xxx

Why does configure script expect an absolute directory name for --prefix?
What are the obstacles for supporting a non-absolute directory name for --prefix?

Basically, it needs to be a fully explicit path [absolute] to ensure there is no relative path confusion at execution time for dependencies and such—and for Unix security default behavior perhaps.

One must type ./configure rather than simply configure to indicate to
the shell that the script is in the current directory. This is
because, as a security precaution, Unix configurations don't search
the current directory for executables. So, to execute programs in that
directory, one must explicitly specify their location.[1]
./configure --libs="-lmpfr -lgmp" 
./configure --prefix=/home/user/local 

The second line tells make to install the final version in /home/user/local
Source

A workaround may be to use $(pwd)/xxx with --prefix parameter if you cd or pushd to the directory you need it to be in relative wise it will make it absolute for you dynamically that way expanding it that way using $(pwd) with the parameter instead.
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/xxx

Supporting Resources

What does --prefix do exactly when used in ./configure?
Is it better to use $(pwd) or $PWD?
Specifying local install directory for ./configure for pango-1.32.6


I see other posts suggest ${pwd} in that format so may be worth testing. I'm not certain if the cd or pushd is needed if you got that $(pwd) baked into the script, so test accordingly to confirm this for certain.

In shells, $(pwd) is command expansion, ${pwd} is variable expansion, and there is no variable named 'pwd' out of the box – the latter would work in Bash/zsh as uppercase${PWD} or $PWD but not as lowercase pwd.
